# No reflect.Type in Type structure in v1.11.6

Tags: go-ethereum

github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum v1.9.6 has this structure in https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/v1.9.6/accounts/abi/type.go:

```
// Type is the reflection of the supported argument type
type Type struct {
    Elem *Type
    Kind reflect.Kind
    Type reflect.Type
    Size int
    T    byte // Our own type checking

    stringKind string // holds the unparsed string for deriving signatures

    // Tuple relative fields
    TupleElems    []*Type  // Type information of all tuple fields
    TupleRawNames []string // Raw field name of all tuple fields
}

but now in v1.11.6  version it has :

type Type struct {
    Elem *Type
    Size int
    T    byte // Our own type checking

    stringKind string // holds the unparsed string for deriving signatures

    // Tuple relative fields
    TupleRawName  string       // Raw struct name defined in source code, may be empty.
    TupleElems    []*Type      // Type information of all tuple fields
    TupleRawNames []string     // Raw field name of all tuple fields
    TupleType     reflect.Type // Underlying struct of the tuple
}
```

what to return as reflect.Type for eabi.BoolTy, eabi.IntTy, eabi.UintTy, eabi.StringTy  :

```
func createTypeFromABI(t *eabi.Type) (reflect.Type, error) {
    switch t.T {
    case eabi.BoolTy, eabi.IntTy, eabi.UintTy, eabi.StringTy:
        return t.Type, nil
    ....
```

The last line gives compilation error: "Unresolved reference 'Type'"  .
What should be use instead of old code if when I migrate from v1.9.6 to v1.11.6 ?